# How to Distinct Values from Different Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table like :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 24 |
| 24 | 13 |
| 16 | 89 |
| 89 | 16 |

Since they include the same values in different columns for example 16-89 89-16 doesn't make a difference for my table and they duplicate. Can you help me on how to remove them? What I wanna reach is

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 24 |
| 16 | 89 |

Or

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 24 | 13 |
| 89 | 16 |

Doesn't make any difference for my data. Thank you all.

I couldn't reach anything. I tried to Distinct data but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Try NOT EXISTS switched columns

Comment: Hint : **greatest** and **least** functions

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `LEAST` and `GREATEST`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS ColumnA, GREATEST(ColumnA, ColumnB) ColumnB
FROM mytable
```

[Demo on sql server 2022](https://dbfiddle.uk/h1s879Ym)

If `LEAST` and `GREATEST` are not supported :

```
SELECT DISTINCT IIF(ColumnA < ColumnB, ColumnA, ColumnB) AS ColumnA, -- LEAST
                IIF(ColumnA > ColumnB, ColumnA, ColumnB) AS ColumnB  -- GREATEST
FROM mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/yT6IvA1I)

Comment: hello, I use Microsoft SQL and get  "'LEAST' is not a recognized built-in function name." this error. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you check my recent edit

Comment: Glad to hear :) consider accept/vote my answer if you see it useful https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers